# How to log blocked user agents and blocked ips via htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, block, agent

I have an *.htaccess* file with something like the following, but I have no idea who it will block, if anyone. Can someone please tell me how I can write a log file of blocked user agents and IPs.

```
RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Acunetix [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ZyBorg [NC]
        RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Comment: Is your Q about the rule at all or just about logging blocked user agents/IPs?

Answer (score 1):

You are not blocking them, your are redirecting them to a 403 -Forbidden. (You should block them from the firewall, using a combination of `Fail2Ban` and `iptables` or something like that)

Sine you are not blocking them, I am sure you can see the requests in the `access.log` (you can use `grep 403 access.log`)

---

You can redirect them to a page `x.php` an log whatever you need from them. And even better, you can include `x.php` in your `robots.txt` (usually Bad-Crawlers disobey robots.txt instructions) and trap them too

x.php Code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("crawlers.txt", 'a+');
$log = date('m-d-Y H:i:s') . " [" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "] http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
fwrite($file, $log . "\n");
```

If you need more information, please read this page. It should have everything that you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php